# Is this diaper rash caused by starting on solids?

Tags: infant, allergies, diaper-rash, solids

My son is 5 months and just started solids last week. So far, so good, until today.

My wife just told me that she thinks our son is having a reaction to something he ate. She said that his BM had the look/consistency of peanut butter and that he has a very bad diaper rash (with some blistering). In the last 48 hours he has eaten a few bites each of Earth's Best apples (yesterday) and Earth's Best carrots (today).

Has anyone else seen something like this, with either Earth's Best brand or just with apples or carrots in general? If so, what did you do about it?

Comment: My daughter started on solids recently, and even though she only had a few bites at first, her BM had the consistency of peanut butter as well.  I think that part is normal.

Comment: Is the child teething?

Comment: @DanBeale yes he is. He already has 2 teeth and has started gnawing on everything in sight (again).

Comment: Nappy rash can be caused by teething, so maybe that's part of the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you describe is a fairly normal reaction when introducing solids.

Try leaving out these products for a few days and see if the rash goes away. Try another brand (or even other foods) and see if the rash returns.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at peanut butter... remembering baby poop... not seeing much difference... could you be more specific in what you notice?

I've never tried the "Earth's Best" brand, but carrots often cause constipation or other troubles when introduced as a first food.  My advice is to wait on carrots until your son has been accustomed to gentler foods (fruits, baby rice cereal, chicken) and before introducing straight carrots, introduce them in a mix with other foods (like the pureed chicken or beef stews).

I'm not sure about the diaper rash: in my experience, allergic reactions and chemical sensitivities tend to cause rash at the exposure site(s), or an all-body rash, but not diaper rash.  I'd start by eliminating the carrots (for now), treating the diaper rash as you normally would -- including changing diapers more frequently -- and if it doesn't improve, talk to your pediatrician.  It may be coincidence that it cropped up just now.